# Google Data Studio MySQL Date Issue

Tags: mysql, magento, etl, looker-studio

I'm struggling with an issue.

I'm pulling data into Data Studio from a Magento Database, through MySQL. I'm trying to group revenues by year.

I have a date "created_at" which I transform into a year, and "grand_total". The issue is the split I get between year, which is different from the one I get querying the database directly using SQL.

Any ideas why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score -1):

I sometimes use data from a mySQL database and for datetime I use

```
CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), myDateColumn)
```

Seems to work.